# Templated C++ class unexpectedly inaccessible on recompile

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a class implementing a templated buffer structure which I use all over my code.

```
template <typename T> class CBuf
{
public:
    unsigned int TotItems;
    unsigned int buflen;

    CBuf (unsigned int len);
    ~CBuf ();
    void clear ();
    void fillWithZeroes ();
    bool addFrame (T *frame, unsigned int fs);
    int getFrame (T *frame, unsigned int fs);
    int peekFrame (T *frame, unsigned int fs);
    int copyOut (T *pBuf, unsigned int len);
    void copyIn (T *pBuf, unsigned int len);
    void copy ( CBuf<T> &other );

private:
    HeapBlock<T> buffer;
    unsigned int addpos, getpos;
};
```

This is used in various parts of my code with no problems and has been working for years.

The object is inherited by another buffer like so:

```
class FrameBuffer : public CBuf<unsigned char>
{
private:
    int numFrames;

public:
    /** error codes that may be returned */
    enum errors {
                    OK,         /*!< OK */
                    BUFFERFULL, /*!< the action has failed becuase it would cause a buffer overflow */
                    NODATA,     /*!< the action has failed because there is insufficient data */
                    TOOSMALL    /*!< the supplied buffer is too small to receive the frame */
                 };
    /**
```

Again this works fine. Yesterday I did a full recompile of the code after deleting all generated  files. Suddenly the following code:

```
class SoundBuffer : public JitterBuffer
{
    private:
        CBuf<float> historyBuffer;                 // maintain a running history
```

Generates

```
CBuf is a private member of CBuf<unsigned char>
```

and the restriction traces back to the definition of FrameBuffer. JitterBuffer inherits the FrameBuffer class and includes the FrameBuffer.h file in its own include. This is the only place that FrameBuffer and CBuf are used together, and the only place that the error is generated. I've tried everything but cannot fix the error - and this was all compiling nicely until yesterday.  Modifying JitterBuffer to inherit differently is possible, but will take a hell of a lot of work in a complex piece of code which works fine and is very difficult to test. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: "*JitterBuffer inherits the FrameBuffer class*": Is this inheritance private? Try `::CBuf<float>` instead of `CBuf<float>` to avoid finding a private injected class name by unqualified name lookup.

Comment: Thanks for that. It solved the compilation problem, but I then got a linkage error saying that  none of the CBuf method symbols were found. If found a workaround by moving all of class code into the header file, but clearly this is not the correct solution

Comment: Member functions of templates generally must be implemented in the header file, that is correct. (There are alternatives using explicit instantiation, but they have limited use.) If you add the missing information I asked for to your question, then I can write up an answer explaining the problem. In particular GCC and Clang have different behaviors for this case, so it would be an interesting question if complete. With a proper [repro] it would be even better.

Comment: Hi - I've tried inheritance both private and public with the same result. Currently using clang compiler. I'll put up a minimal reproducible example a little later.